# Go worker pattern for warm workers

Tags: go

I'm working on a problem where I have a set of "warm workers". That means that they are maintained in memory, maintain their own contexts and are callable. I've been looking at various Go worker implementations but all depend on closures or simple calculation functions that return results.

I found an example of a worker that lets me spin up my contexts and distribute tasks to them based on a max queue and max routine limit: https://github.com/cahitbeyaz/job-worker/blob/master/main.go#L131

However this pattern doesn't allow me to return a result from the context and feed it back. I'm also using a web server and so the web handler has to receive the result and respond accordingly.

Is there a specific/better pattern I should/could follow or a way I could adapt the job-worker example?

PS. At first I thought I could create a ResultQueue where results are pushed back and consumed by the web handler. I don't think the ordering of the queue can be counted on though.

Comment: share some actual code please.

Comment: You could use that example, receive the results from a result channel, and order them.

Comment: @mh-cbon the code is in the line. Either way I solved the issue. Answer posted below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is incredibly simple (I was definitely over-complicating it). Not sure how efficient this actually is but doubt it's not too terrible. Suggestions for a better pattern are still welcome:

In the job definition declare a channel to feed back the result:

```
type Job struct {
    Request string
    Params  []string
    Result chan Result
}
```

Inside your worker rather than just exiting with a return, pass the result struct over the channel:

```
job.Result <- Result{
    Response: result.String(),
    Headers:  []string{},
}
```

Now inside the web handler just wait on the channel:

```
disatcher.jobQueue <- job
result := <- job.Result
```

Silly me. Don't know why that had to take 2 hours of effort. :-p lesson learned: Go concurrency is POWERFUL. Just don't overthink it.